# Why does the rails scaffolding add status unprocessable_entity for json save errors but not for HTML save errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, controller

Both JSON and HTML are being processed over HTTP. REST more or less encourages usage of valid http error codes for responses to API calls.

Why is it when we ask rails for the HTML representation of the create result we get HTTP 200 even if there are validation errors and we get HTTP 422 for JSON?

```
# POST /apples
# POST /apples.json
def create
  @apple = Apple.new(apple_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @apple.save
      format.html { redirect_to @apple, notice: 'Apple was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @apple }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @apple.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Because practicality wins out. There is no advantage in serving up a 422 to people sitting at their web browser filling in a form.

Comment: Is there a disadvantage to doing it? I guess there must be with some browsers?

Answer (score 2):

For HTML requests, the default behavior is to just show the resulting markup, nothing special needs to be done after an HTML request is served (this is Rails scaffolds' defaults)

For other formats, like JSON, the client will most likely want to know the status code in order to take action. The client might be expecting a JSON response with the key "foos" for *any* status code that comes in the response, but depending on the status code, different things should happen with these "foos". This is not the case with HTML responses, because everything is handled on the server side, within the scope of the Rails application.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

In 2020+ these statuses are very helpful in case one is using [Hotwire Turbo](https://turbo.hotwire.dev/).

[Redirecting After a Form Submission @ turbo.hotwire.dev handbook](https://turbo.hotwire.dev/handbook/drive#redirecting-after-a-form-submission)

> Turbo Drive handles form submissions in a manner similar to link clicks. The key difference is that form submissions can issue stateful requests using the HTTP POST method, while link clicks only ever issue stateless HTTP GET requests.
>
> After a stateful request from a form submission, Turbo Drive expects the server to return an HTTP 303 redirect response, which it will then follow and use to navigate and update the page without reloading.
>
> The exception to this rule is when the response is rendered with either a 4xx or 5xx status code. This allows form validation errors to be rendered by having the server respond with 422 Unprocessable Entity and a broken server to display a “Something Went Wrong” screen on a 500 Internal Server Error.
>
> The reason Turbo doesn’t allow regular rendering on 200 is that browsers have built-in behavior for dealing with reloads on POST visits where they present a “Are you sure you want to submit this form again?” dialogue that Turbo can’t replicate. Instead, Turbo will stay on the current URL upon a form submission that tries to render, rather than change it to the form action, since a reload would then issue a GET against that action URL, which may not even exist.